# How to know Phone State as a service?

Tags: java, android

**The Problem:**

What I want the app to do is checking a phone's current call state in the background. Now, for making an app that works in background we need a service(source codes in the next section), but the only way I have managed to do this is by using a receiver. The issue with the receiver is that it is not always running if you kill the app in the background. Now this seems a fairly simple question, but I am new to JAVA.

**Source Codes**

This is my main service's OnStartCommand file:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID).setContentTitle("asdaff").setContentText("asdas").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android_black_24dp).build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
    TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
            (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    PhoneStateListener callStateListener;
    callStateListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
            String stateString = "N/A";
            switch (state) {
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                    stateString = "Idle";
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stateString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
                    toast.show();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                    stateString = "Off Hook";
                    Toast toast1 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stateString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast1.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
                    toast1.show();
                    break;
                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                    stateString = "Ringing";
                    Toast toast2 = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), stateString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                    toast2.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0,0);
                    toast2.show();
                    break;
            }
        }
    };
    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

**Edit**

Used startForegroundservice() and it still does not work. I have the phone permission. Please tell if you need more of the source code to tell the problem.

Comment: Use foreground service

Comment: I saw a YouTube tutorial on foreground service which told me to make a class that extends under Service and make oncreate ondestroy and onstartcommand functions. Is there any difference between service and foreground service?

Comment: Start foregroundservice with `startForegroundService()` https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out. The issue is in the onStartCommand method itself. When using a phone state listener, you need to have the listener registered to the telephony manager.

```
telephonyManager.listen(callStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
```

Now, I thought this is one of those "Google-able" Things, that have a proper beginner mistake warning that may help anyone who is going to commit such a stupid mistake(i.e, me).

I am Writing this answer so that anyone who comes across this may no what not to do.
Cheers.